# Are MMORPG quest questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have finished a quest in an MMOPRG, but don't know which NPC to speak to to get the reward.

I have tried everything I can think of to no avail. This is blocking me in a quest line. Is it on topic to ask about the NPC here?

Comment: A quest in a single player game or a quest in an MMORPG - there's not that much difference, really... The only issue that could arise is that the content gets updated making the answers obsolete, but that already happens with some single player games, so I don't see why this wouldn't be on-topic...

Comment: I’m really curious. Why do you think that it would not be on topic?  I don’t mean to be condescending.

Comment: Don't worry, you don't sound condescending. Tldr; "better safe than sorry" ..........  I am fairly active on quite a few S.E sites, but on those, like this, where I am a n00b, I have encountered downvoting. Obviously,  part of that it me being new, but some of it may be the S.O attitude of the past few years - "let's punish him until he learns (or flees)", where low point users are more subject to chastisement. I am used to the privileges that points bring, have already been downvoted here and am wary or being so again.  Plus, I might want those points to offer as a bonus one day

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes.

I can't see a single reason why a question like this would be off-topic.
It is an in-game problem, which requires an in-game solution. It does not matter if the game is an MMORPG or a single player match three game.

Comment: How do I win a singleplayer match three game? The AI keeps putting one down right when I match two and now I can't match three.

Comment: @Yuuki I would downvote that question, but it would be a valid (although very badly worded) question. If it asked for a specific strategy, it'd be better.